# Apply method to certain objects of an array where some of them implement and interface

Tags: java

How can I have a method that goes through all the elements of an array and modify just the elements that implement an interface aplying an interface method to it?

With "array[i] instanceof SomeInterface" I can check if the element implements or not the interface but I can't apply an interface method because all the objects don't implement it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < figuresArray.length; i++) {
        if(figuresArray[i] instanceof Volume) {
            figuresArray[i].incrementVolume();
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work because figuresArray[i] is a Figure object and doesn't know the method incrementVolume()

Comment: Add some code of what you have/tried.

Comment: Use cast, Luke.

Comment: `((InterfaceName) array[i]).interfaceMethod();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to cast the object to the correct type so that you can call the method on it.

```
for (Object objectLike : figuresArray) {
    if (NameOfInterfaceToImplement.class.isInstance(objectLike)) {
        NameOfInterfaceToImplement interfaceLike = NameOfInterfaceToImplement.class.cast(objectLike);
        interfaceLike.incrementVolume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can check if an element implements certain interface using `array[i] instanceof SomeInterface`, in order to call a method from that interface, you need to cast the element to the interface like `((SomeInterface)array[i]).customMethod()`.

On the other hand, casting is an unsafe operation and I would analyze if you really need to do that or maybe change the design to not require casting at all.